# Making python files executable in Ubuntu

Tags: python, windows-7, ubuntu

In windows to make one of my codes execute all I have to do is double click on the file. However, I can't seem to figure out how to do a similar task in Ubuntu.

Comment: This has nothing to do with .pyw files (they just prevent the console from appearing but are otherwise exactly the same).

Answer (score 7):

Make sure you have `#!/usr/bin/env python` as the first line of your script, then in your shell do:

```
chmod +x file.py
./file.py
```

Comment: To the OP: This is what you need, just don't forget to add something along the lines of `#! /usr/bin/python` as the first line. the `#!` is the unix-y way of telling the computer what executable is needed to run the script.

Answer (score 4):

.pyw files are just .py files that have been renamed so that Windows file associations will launch them with the console-free Python interpreter instead of the regular one.

To get run-on-doubleclick working on Ubuntu, first, you need to make sure the kernel sees the script as executable and knows what to do with it. To do that:

1. Use either the Nautilus file properties dialog or the chmod command to mark it executable (`chmod +x whatever.pyw`)
2. Make sure that the first line in the file says `#!/usr/bin/env python` (See [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) for more info)
3. Make sure the file was saved with Unix-style LF (`\n`) line-endings rather than DOS/Windows-style CRLF (`\r\n`) line-endings. (The kernel expects Unix-style line endings for step 2 and, if you forget, it sees the CR (`\r`) character as part of the path and errors out)

You can test whether you've completed these steps properly by running your script in a terminal window. (`cd` to the directory it's in and run `./your_script.pyw`)

If it works, then Nautilus should just automatically display an "Edit or run?" dialog when you double-click. However, it's been a while since I've used GNOME, so I can't be sure.

If it doesn't, try renaming the file to `.py`. (I remember Nautilus having a "Extension matches header?" safety check which may not be aware that .pyw is a valid synonym for .py)

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the permission for the file for it to be executable using `chmod`. See the [manpages](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/chmod.1posix.html) for chmod for details.